# How to set Stripping Level for iOS in Unity

Tags: ios, iphone, build, unity-game-engine, filesize

Where can I find the option to set the Stripping Level for iOS? I couldn't find it in Build Settings -> Player Settings. I am using Unity 5.3.4.

Answer (score 1):

iOS in Unity now uses IL2CPP instead of mono.

IL2CPP automatically strips unused stuff, so you can't customise it in the build settings anymore beyond the 'Strip Engine Code' tick box.

See the 'Stripping with IL2CPP' section of this document for more detailed information: [iOS Optimisation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html)

Comment: When I checked the log, I saw the inclusion of many assets which I think were unused. How do I enable IL2CPP?

Comment: stripping is not the stripping of unused assets, it is the stripping of unused code.

Comment: Is there a way to disable the inclusion of unused assets? I think it is automatic for Android APK.

Comment: Also, one of the library files in the iOS build was 1GB, when my Android APK was only 93MB. Do you think IL2CPP will help? How do I enable IL2CPP?

Comment: You can enable IL2CPP using the "Scripting Backend" option in the Player settings. Note that it will likely make the binary size larger, because it will build both armv7 (32-bit) and arm64 (64-bit) binary slices by default. Build size can be misleading on iOS though. See this thread for more details: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-3-x-build-size-increase-faq.383533/